# Cannot open a SQL Server 2000 DTS package I imported into SQL Server 2008

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, sql-server, dts

I am running into a problem trying to open a SQL Server 2000 DTS package I imported into SQL Server 2008. I set up a new server and installed a fresh install of SQL Server 2008.  The database I need to run is a SQL Server 2000 database. I moved the database over with no problem but there are a few DTS packages that need to run in legacy on SQL Server 2008. I exported the DTS packages I need out of SQL2000 and imported them successfully into SQL Server 2008. My SQL Server 2008 is x64.

I can see the DTS packages under Data Transformation Service in Legacy but when I try to open the package I get this message. "SQL Server 2000 DTS Designer components are required to edit DTS packages.  Install the special web download, "SQL Server 2000 DTS Designer components" to use this feature.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.DtsObjectExplorerUI)"

I downloaded the components and installed them and still get this error.  I researched and found an article about this not working on x64 so I have an x86 machine that I installed the SQL Server 2008 tools and tried to open the package from there and got the same error.

I have spent days on this and need help.  Has anyone run across this and can tell me what to do.  If you have solved this problem, please help me out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem and eventually gave up.

My workaround was to use one of these approaches:

1. Rewrite the DTS package as a stored procedure, and schedule a job to run it as appropriate.
2. Rewrite the DTS package as a SSIS process.
3. Import the legacy DTS package onto a SQL Server 2005 instance, and use linked server's to update the database now running under SQL Serve 2008.

Comment: I hear you.  I finally decided to use the migration wizard to convert the DTS package to SSIS and ran it that way.  I was actually pleasantly surprised that my test DTS package migrated fairly easily considering it was somewhat complex.  I had to do some minor configuration to the connection but it worked ok.  I guess I will continue on and migrate the rest of the packages and see what happens.  Thanks for the info.